# Can't add member to the Class programmatically using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I try to add a method to the class using Roslyn.
I parse .cs file and get the decidered class.

```
SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseFile(Path);
CompilationUnitSyntax root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
MemberDeclarationSyntax firstMember = root.Members[0];
TypeDeclarationSyntax lClassDeclarationSyntax = (TypeDeclarationSyntax)NamespaceDeclaration.Members[1];
```

Then i create an instance of the type MemberDeclaration

```
MethodDeclarationSyntax lMethodDeclarationSyntax= Syntax.MethodDeclaration(
Syntax.List<AttributeListSyntax>(),
Syntax.TokenList(),
Syntax.IdentifierName("MemoryStream"),
null,
Syntax.Identifier("Serialize"),
null,
Syntax.ParameterList(),
Syntax.List<TypeParameterConstraintClauseSyntax>(),
Syntax.Block(lList));
```

where `lList` is the body of method. 
Then i try to add this instance to the class

```
lClassDeclarationSyntax.Members.Add(lMethodDeclarationSyntax);
```

but nothing in response.
How i can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Roslyn syntax trees are immutable, so the Add method returns a new SyntaxList, it doesn't update it in place.  You probably want something like

```
var newClass = lClassDeclarationSyntax
.WithMembers(lClassDeclarationSyntax.Members.Add(lMethodDeclarationSyntax));
```

This is something we are working on making clearer in the method names.

Comment: And as it does not disrupt the structure of the file? For example, I have 2 classes in the file, and I've only got one ... then I need to create a new tree, given the second class, and then save the the tree in a fie cs, assuring removing the old file?

Comment: Or can I simply replace the trees?

Comment: It does not disrupt the file.  If you want a _copy_ of the file with the updated class, you can use root.ReplaceNode to get it with your changes.

Comment: There is also `ClassDeclarations.AddMembers` to add members later. Probaly that api was introduced after your answer.